# Как выцепить авторизированного пользователя

Tags: python, django

Есть вьюшка, в ней надо получить id пользователя стандартной модели django.contrib.auth.models.User который в данный момент авторизирован..

Как это сделать?

Comment: [Элементарно](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user): `request.user.id`

Comment: Спасибо большое! 8)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Экземпляр [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects), доступный в представлениях на основе функций первым параметром, а в представлениях на основе классов вторым или как атрибут самого представления (в зависимости от метода, в котором происходит обращение к нему), содержит атрибут [user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user). [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) устанавливает в этот атрибут экземпляр модели [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) для текущего авторизованного пользователя или [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser) для неавторизованного. В первом случае атрибут `id` будет фактическим значением идентификатора пользователя, во втором `None`.

```
def some_view(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
```

или

```
def SomeView(FormView):
    def form_valid(self):
        user_id = self.request.user.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался и сделал `request.user.id`